# C# decimal tostring format

Tags: c#, format, decimal

I want to create a string from a decimal, whithout the decimal separator;

1,500.00 should become "150000".

What is the proper format for this? (Whithout string.replace , and .)

Thank you!

Comment: This is a weird request; why are you doing this?

Comment: A payment provider requires the amounts to be formatted in cents. So it is not allowed to have a seperator.

Comment: If you need it formatted in cents, then just multiply by `100` and be done with it. The way your question is worded, it sounds way more general than it needs to be - e.g. it's obvious from what you've said that `1,500.001` should be output as `150000`, but your question requires it to be `1500001`.

Answer (score 7):

try:

```
   decimal d = 1500m;
   string s = (100*d).ToString("0");
```

Comment: What if there are more decimals after the decimal place?

Comment: Do you want the extra decimal values ?

Comment: @Meta-Knight: Right, so what if `d = 1500.001`. The current proposal will output `150000` and not `1500001` which is how I am interpreting the request.

Comment: @Jason, I interpreted it as only get two decimal places... @joop ??

Comment: @Charles Bretana: That's quite a leap from "I want to create a string from a decimal, [without] the decimal seperator" to "only get two decimal places."

Comment: @Jason,  I have strong legs... and didn't you see the way he misspelled "seperator"? That's a clear indication he only wants 2 decimal places...  actually, if it matters to you, I got this assumption only from his example - which had two decimal places...  but I'm not saying you're wrong...  ...only @joop knows.

Comment: @Charles Bretana: You made me laugh.

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions:

- Create your own NumberFormatInfo and CultureInfo and pass it along to ToString.
- Multiply the number by 100, then use `.ToString("0")`

Comment: I don't think the NumberFormatInfo thing will work.  .NET does not allow an empty decimal separator.

Comment: Scott P is right; `NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator = String.Empty` will throw.

Comment: I suspect it's so because it is used for parsing as well, and it's kinda tricky to find an empty substring when parsing...

Comment: Hmm... that's disappointing. I think Pavel is right, it must be due to the need to round-trip the result with Parse().

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with `String.Replace` anyway? It's simple and to the point:

```
CultureInfo info = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

decimal m = 1500.00m;
string s = m.ToString("G", info).Replace(".", String.Empty));
Console.WriteLine(s); // outputs "150000"

m = 1500.0m;
string s = m.ToString("G", info).Replace(".", String.Empty));
Console.WriteLine(s); // outputs "15000"

m = 1500.000m;
string s = m.ToString("G", info).Replace(".", String.Empty));
Console.WriteLine(s); // outputs "1500000"


m = 1500.001m;
string s = m.ToString("G", info).Replace(".", String.Empty));
Console.WriteLine(s); // outputs "1500001"

m = 1500.00000000000000000000001m;
string s = m.ToString("G", info).Replace(".", String.Empty));
Console.WriteLine(s); // outputs "150000000000000000000000001"
```

Comment: `"."` should be `info.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator`?

Comment: Eh, it could be but we know that `NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` is `.` when `info` is the culture represented by `en-US`.

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal value = 1500;
Console.WriteLine((value * 100).ToString("0"));
```

Comment: What if there are more decimals after the decimal place?

Comment: It wasn't like that before answer changed, it is correct now thank you for the help!

Comment: sorry, missed that `* 100` in first version; funny thing is one downvote here =)